# I unknowingly coloured my username in Minecraft Pocket Edition. Now my username is blank...and I can't change it

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

(Unknowingly) I coloured my username in MCPE...  Now I can't change or even have a username...it's just a blank space.  I can't play servers and write im the chat.

If you can give me advice without a Jailbreak device being involved, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know how file managers work on IOS, but if you can find a 'games' folder, go in 'com.mojang', 'minecraftpe' and then to 'options.txt', you find your username there that you can modify.

Answer (score -4):

I think you have to delete minecraft then purchase it again.

Comment: Yeah, you're most likely right, I mean that will work, but all my worlds will be deleted.  I spent 2 years in creative to make this one world...  So I will just wait till a bug fix update comes out.